# Are there any standards (even IDE-specific) to refer a certain object from inside a comment string?

Tags: python, pycharm

In Java, in Eclipse at least, there was a way to refer to a certain class, from inside the code documentation. This was cool, as if one refactored the  class (changed its name or moved it in some other package), the comment would also get refactored.

I'm using Pycharm, and i'd like to know if i can do the same thing there.

For example:

```
def myfunction():
    """Does something interesting for the class mypackage.MyClass. 
    See yourpackage.YourClass
    """
    pass
```

I'd like my IDE to recognize `MyClass` and `YourClass` as the fully specified classes they "are".

I know how to do type annotations like so:

```
def myfunc(myarg):
    """
    :type myarg: ClassInThisModule
    :rtype: int
    """
    return 3
```

But this is not sufficient. I want to give examples in the documentation, and link to other areas in the code that might be interesting (classes, functions, modules, etc), and i want the IDE to recognize these things, and refactor them intelligently in case that's needed.

Is this possible? Or would I need to write a plugin if I wanted anything like this.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

Comment: Thanks. Knew about that, but was hoping for some extra tool, perhaps PyCharm Plugin or something, that knew a little more than type hinting.